# Baking a Controller with Cakephp 3.2 using SQLite3 produces an error in the add() and edit() methods, Why is the code being generated incorrectly?

Tags: cakephp, sqlite, cakephp-bake, cakephp-3.2

The error is that when creating the controller code a variable for an associated model is left blank, and that Model's name is left blank.  The error happens when creating the controllers for all of my tables, but here is a complete example of one of them.  I've replicated the problem on a fresh install of cakephp 3.2.

Here is the 2 lines of incorrect code generated, I've included the full details below:

```
$ = $this->Customers->->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('customer', ''));
```

My database configuration in config/app.php:

```
'default' => [
     'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
     'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Sqlite',
     'persistent' => false,
     'host' => 'localhost',
     //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
     'username' => null,
     'password' => null,
     'database' => 'tgr.db',
     'encoding' => 'utf8',
     'timezone' => 'UTC',
     'flags' => [],
     'cacheMetadata' => true,
     'log' => false,
     'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
     'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
]
```

The code created for the add() method which contains the incorrectly created code.

```
public function add(){
    $customer = $this->Customers->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $customer = $this->Customers->patchEntity($customer, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Customers->save($customer)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The customer has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The customer could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $ = $this->Customers->->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('customer', ''));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['customer']);
}
```

My database is stored int the application root and the app finds it and connects correctly from what I can tell. Database Schema:

```
-- Text encoding used: UTF-8
--
PRAGMA foreign_keys = off;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- Table: customers
CREATE TABLE customers (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,district_key INTEGER NOT NULL, name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, short_name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, job_count INTEGER, report_count INTEGER,  FOREIGN KEY (district_key) REFERENCES districts (_id)  );

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
PRAGMA foreign_keys = on;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  My database id columns were _id (from the android default id column) and cakephp bakery was interpriting this to be a related Model with an empty name sense it was taking whatever comes before _id and creating a model for it. I've updated all of my database tables to reflect this and it is working correctly.